# MySQL Relational Database Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, database

To learn databasing, I am creating a movie database.

To associate multiple directors with a movie, I have the following schema:

```
movie(m_ID, ....)

m_director(dirID, dirName)//dirID is a autoincrement primary key

m_directs(dirID, m_ID) //dirID, m_ID are set as foreign Keys in the mysql  

database(InnoDB engine)
```

I have a program that connects to the db that needs to add a movie to the database.

I can easily add a new entry to the movie table and the m_director table, but I am having trouble adding a entry in the m_directs table.

```
INSERT INTO m_director (dirName) VALUES("Jason Reitman");
INSERT INTO m_directs (dirID, m_ID) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), "tt0467406");
```

I am using this sql statement to insert a new director and add the association to the movie. I know the primary key of the movie, but I don't know the `dirID`, so I use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the last id of the director just inserted.

The problem I am having is that I get the following error:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Cannot add or 
update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`siteproducts`.
`m_directs`, CONSTRAINT `m_directs_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`dirID`) 
REFERENCES `m_directs` (`dirID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try selecting LAST_INSERT_ID() instead and make sure that it is the value you are expecting, also try inserting manually with a known good value and see which is incorrect.

Comment: I think you'll need to show us the output of `show create table m_director` and `show create table m_directs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have foreign key for `m_directs.dirID` set to same table and column, not to `m_director.dirID`

Comment: That was the prob, how'd you catch that lol...first time setting up a db is bound to have some minor mistakes..Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

as u write `LAST_INSERT_ID()` , but your insert query on `m_director` is not executed, so last insert_id will come from `movie`  table..

or as per @rdamborsky

you have foreign key for `m_directs.dirID` set to same table and column, not to `m_director.dirID`